# (base): conda, (env1): CPython, (env2): Some python-distro. Possible?

Tags: python, conda

I have a question which arises pretty much instantly after reading all the basics about environments in python. However, I was not able to find anything on the internet. 
Let’s say I have an Anaconda installation and everything works fine. Everybody knows there are many many python distributions out there. Let’s assume, I want to play with some specific distribution (lets say, I am interested in CPython which can be downloaded from python.org). And: I want to have it in an environment isolated from other distributions. Like this:
 
Base-Environment: Conda – Environment 
Environment1:  CPython 
Environment2: Miniconda-distribution 
Environment3: Some other distribution and so on…

I want the Environment1 to be created on the basis of files published by the Python Software Foundation (python.org). Similar applies for other environments. 
Can I achieve that using conda? Can I achieve that for some specific distributions only? How can I achieve that using conda? Can someone write a comprehensive answer?

Comment: You cannot do this with Conda, sorry. Conda manages packages in the Conda ecosystem. However, the Python installed by Conda is still CPython. Also, FWIW, Miniconda is just a bare Conda environment with only Conda and Python installed, and you can use Miniconda to install the `anaconda` package to get the equivalent of installing Anaconda.

Comment: Yes, this ist not possible. You can't take python from python.org and incorporate it into Conda.